# Insert a wide box to write

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have this tikz display and I want to make something like a `minipage` to write thing on each day. I'm not a master of tikz.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calendar, shapes.misc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
        inner sep=3 pt,
        dayname/.style={%
            node font=\footnotesize, 
        },
        daynumber/.style={%
            anchor=north east,
            node font=\normalsize\bfseries, 
        },
        activitie/.style={%
            anchor=north east,
            node font=\normalsize, 
        },
        xscale = 10,
        yscale=-3
    ]

    \node (saturday_number) at (-0.1,6) [daynumber] {14};
    \node [base right = 1em of saturday_number, anchor=base west] [dayname] {Sábado};

    \node (sunday_number) at (0.45,6) [daynumber] {15};
    \node [base right = 1em of sunday_number, anchor=base west] [dayname] {Domingo};
    \draw (-0.25,7) -- (0.99,7);

    \node (friday_number) at (-0.1,5) [daynumber] {13};
    \node [base right = 1em of friday_number, anchor=base west] [dayname] {Viernes};
    \draw (-0.25,6) -- (0.99,6);

    \node (thursday_number) at (-0.1,4) [daynumber] {12};
    \node [base right = 1em of thursday_number, anchor=base west] [dayname] {Jueves};
    \draw (-0.25,5) -- (0.99,5);

    \node (wednesday_number) at (-0.1,3) [daynumber] {11};
    \node [base right = 1em of wednesday_number, anchor=base west] [dayname] {Miércoles};
    \draw (-0.25,4) -- (0.99,4);

    \node (tuesday_number) at (-0.1,2) [daynumber] {10};
    \node [base right = 1em of tuesday_number, anchor=base west] [dayname] {Martes};
    \draw (-0.25,3) -- (0.99,3);

    \node (monday_number) at (-0.1,1) [daynumber] {9};
    \node [base right = 1em of monday_number, anchor=base west] [dayname] {Lunes};
    \draw (-0.25,2) -- (0.99,2);
    
    \node (year_number) at (-0.15,1) [anchor = south east, minimum height = 2em] {2022};
    \node [base right = 1em of year_number, anchor=base west, node font=\large] {Diciembre};
    \draw (-0.25,1) -- (0.99,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: If you use `text width=<width>` on a node, it's content will be set in a minipage of that width. Can you show us what your final product should look like? You're loading the `calendar` library but don't use it … it can do a lot for your automatically.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/610956/197451

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I posted a question where you can find the whole solution, and I'm asking for some help doing it better here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/667262/upgrade-my-weekly-calendar